# Как прочитать память напрямую по адресу (Rust)?

Tags: ассемблер, память, rust, qemu, микроархитектура

Я изучал работу с **голым железом** на `Rust`. Начал я с VGA: Узнал, что могу записывать в него данные вот так:

```rust
fn main(){
    buffer: unsafe { &mut *(0xb8000 as *mut Buffer) };
    
}
struct Buffer {
    chars: [[Volatile<ScreenChar>; BUFFER_WIDTH]; BUFFER_HEIGHT]
}
pub struct VgaWriter {
    column_position: usize,
    buffer: &'static mut Buffer
}
// ...
```

То есть по сути напрямую укзать: У меня по адресу `0xb8000` лежит VGA буфер, хочу туда писать информацию. И это работает (ну или хотя бы не вылетает) (тестирую в `QEMU`, собирая как загрузочный образ через crate `bootloader`).

Теперь я пошел дальше: Я захотел записать что-нибудь в serial port. Я узнал, что в QEMU он находится по адресу `0x3f8`.
Теперь я захотел что-нибудь считать с него и с соседних адресов, похожим образом (как я понял, это как бы входы следующих пинов порта):

```rust
let a = unsafe { &mut *(0x3f8  as *mut [u8; 25]) };
    for i in a{
        print!("{}", i);
    }
```

Такой код приводит к циклическому перезапуску образа в QEMU, несколько раз в секунду, даже не выпадая в панику. Я подумал, что настроил что-то не так, но работа с портом через `uart_16550` работает отлично:

```rust
use uart_16550::SerialPort;
fn main(){
    unsafe{ SerialPort::new(0x3f8).write_str("Hello world"); };
}
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрев внутрь, я понял, что где-то в глубине, считывание с адреса происходит примерно следующим образом:

```rust
fn main(){
    for i in 0..25{
        let value: u8;
        unsafe {
            asm!("in al, dx", out("al") value, in("dx") 0x3f8+i, options(nomem, nostack, preserves_flags));
        }
        println!("{}", value);
    }
}
```

И да, таким образом я могу получить какую-то информацию на экран (в как раз таки VGA режиме) (пока не знаю как ей пользоваться, но вопрос в другом):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой вопрос состоит в следующем: Почему я могу записывать и читать в VGA напрямую порт по адресу `0xb8000`, но не могу считывать в адресе `0x3f8`, и вообще в других адресах.

И, ещё важнее, почему я всё-таки могу делать это, но только через `asm` команды?

Как я могу обойти это ограничение? Или я вообще делаю что-то в корне неправильное/

Comment: Конечно, зависит от конкретного UART-а, но обычно читать регистр данных можно только, если данные поступили (даже если UART был правильно инициализирован). Наличие в fifo данных  нужно смотреть в регистре статуса. Где именно расположены конкретные регистры относительно базового адреса UART-а см. в документации на ваш UART

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порты ввода-вывода - это порты ввода-вывода. А память это память. Через ассемблерную инструкцию `in` производится чтение с порта ввода-вывода. Процессор х86 имеет некие фичи, применив которые можно работать какбы с памятью - но реально с портами. Но чтобы это работало, его надо настроить. Так просто работать не будет. В каждой ОС это настраивается по разному. В линуксе ключевые слова ioremap, request_mem_region, request_region выведут вас на нужные статьи.

Кстати говоря, современный процессор частенько переупорядочивает команды, которые выполняет, и компилятор тоже - для ускорения работы. То есть если вы пишите:

```
a = 4
b = 5
```

Реальный то порядок присваивания неопределен. Может присвоиться в том порядке, как написано - а может и наоборот: сначала присвоится `b` и только потом `a`. И всякие чтения тоже может переупорядочивать. Если это работа с железом, или многопоточное использование, то это может оказаться большой проблемой, и надо делать дополнительные телодвижения, чтобы такого переупорядочивания не было. В двух словах так, дальше - ищите статьи с примерами.